# counting the number of document containing a specific term

Tags: java

lets say i has a term ' about'.

I wanted to know whether a text file contain this word.

If yes, it will increment the number of text file containing the word by 1 in a counter.

Any advice on how to do this ?

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? If this is homework, it should also have the homework tag.

Comment: Based on your previous questions, I think you are working towards TF/IDF. Is it the case that you are looking for the number of times that one or more terms appear in one or more documents? Please be more specific in your question in order to get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// class declaration ...
private static String readFile(String fileName) {
    String data = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line = ""; line = in.readLine(); line != null)
            string.append(line).append("\n");
        in.close();
        data = line.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Oops: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
    return data;
}

public int filesContaining(String phrase, String... files) {
    int count = 0;
    for (String file : files) {
        if (readFile(file).contains(phrase))
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Then use it like:

```
int count = classInstance.filesContaining("about", "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt");
```

And it returns how many of file1, file2, and file3 contain the word "about".